# Custom sorting in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have python pandas dataframe, in which a column contains month name.

How can I  do a custom sort using a dictionary, for example:

```
custom_dict = {'March':0, 'April':1, 'Dec':3}
```

Comment: Does a columns contain month name mean that there is a column which contains month names (as my answer), or many columns with column names as month names (as eumiro's)?

Comment: The accepted answer is outdated, and is also technically incorrect, as `pd.Categorical` does not interpret the categories as ordered by default. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54301218/4909087).

Comment: @AndyHayden: clearly: *"one single column, which contains month names (as string or categorical)"* (your interpretation, not eumiro's)

Answer (score 242, accepted):

Pandas 0.15 introduced [Categorical Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html), which allows a much clearer way to do this:

First make the month column a categorical and specify the ordering to use.

```
In [21]: df['m'] = pd.Categorical(df['m'], ["March", "April", "Dec"])

In [22]: df  # looks the same!
Out[22]:
   a  b      m
0  1  2  March
1  5  6    Dec
2  3  4  April
```

Now, when you sort the month column it will sort with respect to that list:

```
In [23]: df.sort_values("m")
Out[23]:
   a  b      m
0  1  2  March
2  3  4  April
1  5  6    Dec
```

*Note: if a value is not in the list it will be converted to NaN.*

---

An older answer for those interested...

You could create an intermediary series, and [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) on that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 'March'],[5, 6, 'Dec'],[3, 4, 'April']], columns=['a','b','m'])
s = df['m'].apply(lambda x: {'March':0, 'April':1, 'Dec':3}[x])
s.sort_values()

In [4]: df.set_index(s.index).sort()
Out[4]: 
   a  b      m
0  1  2  March
1  3  4  April
2  5  6    Dec
```

---

As commented, in newer pandas, Series has a [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) method to do this more elegantly:

```
s = df['m'].replace({'March':0, 'April':1, 'Dec':3})
```

*The slight difference is that this won't raise if there is a value outside of the dictionary (it'll just stay the same).*

Comment: `s = df['m'].replace({'March':0, 'April':1, 'Dec':3})` works for line 2 as well -- just for the sake of anyone learning pandas like me

Comment: @kdauria good spot! (been a while since I wrote this!) replace definitely best option, another is to use `.apply({'March':0, 'April':1, 'Dec':3}.get)` :) In 0.15 we'll have Categorical Series/columns, so the best way will be to use that and then sort will just work.

Comment: @AndyHayden I've taken the liberty of replacing the second line with the 'replace' method. I hope that is Ok.

Comment: @AndyHayden edit rejected, but I still think it is a reasonable change.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I missed it, thanks for the edit! I've appended your comment and also updated with the newer categorical method - which I think is a little neater :).

Comment: @AndyHayden the categorical method is returning the `SettingWithCopyWarning` in `pandas 0.18.1` is there a new idiom to follow?

Comment: @toasteez I can't reproduce that in 0.18.1 myself, what are you doing specifically to get that? (There's a warning on sort; new api is sort_values).

Comment: @AndyHayden I've logged a bug my code [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37279260/why-doesnt-pandas-allow-a-categorical-column-to-be-used-in-groupby)   Bug logged #13204

Comment: Just make sure you use `df.sort_values("m")` in newer pandas (instead of `df.sort("m")`), otherwise you'll get a `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort'` ;)

Comment: The first solution does not really solve the problem of custom sorting without typing in the explicit order, or am I missing something? For example, how would I sort the `m` column by length of the month's name using `pd.Categorical`?

Comment: 'Unknown' categories and None is not supported  as categorical series.

Comment: Note that this would break aggregation because of issue <https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13204>.

Answer (score 92):

## pandas >= 1.1

You will soon be able to use `sort_values` with `key` argument:

```
pd.__version__
# '1.1.0.dev0+2004.g8d10bfb6f'

custom_dict = {'March': 0, 'April': 1, 'Dec': 3} 
df

   a  b      m
0  1  2  March
1  5  6    Dec
2  3  4  April

df.sort_values(by=['m'], key=lambda x: x.map(custom_dict))

   a  b      m
0  1  2  March
2  3  4  April
1  5  6    Dec
```

The `key` argument takes as input a Series and returns a Series. This series is internally argsorted and the sorted indices are used to reorder the input DataFrame. If there are multiple columns to sort on, the key function will be applied to each one in turn. See [Sorting with keys](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew/v1.1.0.html#sorting-with-keys).

---

## pandas <= 1.0.X

One simple method is using the output [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`Series.argsort`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.argsort.html) to index into `df` using [`DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) (since argsort produces sorted integer positions); since you have a dictionary; this becomes easy.

```
df.iloc[df['m'].map(custom_dict).argsort()]

   a  b      m
0  1  2  March
2  3  4  April
1  5  6    Dec
```

If you need to sort in **descending order**, invert the mapping.

```
df.iloc[(-df['m'].map(custom_dict)).argsort()]

   a  b      m
1  5  6    Dec
2  3  4  April
0  1  2  March
```

Note that this only works on numeric items. Otherwise, you will need to workaround this using [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), and accessing the index:

```
df.loc[df['m'].map(custom_dict).sort_values(ascending=False).index]

   a  b      m
1  5  6    Dec
2  3  4  April
0  1  2  March
```

More options are available with `astype` (this is deprecated now), or [`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Categorical.html#pandas-categorical), but you need to specify `ordered=True` for it to work *correctly*.

```
# Older version,
# df['m'].astype('category', 
#                categories=sorted(custom_dict, key=custom_dict.get), 
#                ordered=True)
df['m'] = pd.Categorical(df['m'], 
                         categories=sorted(custom_dict, key=custom_dict.get), 
                         ordered=True)
```

Now, a simple [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) call will do the trick:

```
df.sort_values('m')
 
   a  b      m
0  1  2  March
2  3  4  April
1  5  6    Dec
```

The categorical ordering will also be honoured when `groupby` sorts the output.

Comment: You've already emphasized it, but I'd like to reiterate in case someone else skims and misses it: Pandas Categorical sets `ordered=None` by default. If not set, the ordering will be wrong, or break on V23. Max function in particular gives a TypeError (Categorical is not ordered for operation max).

Comment: +1 for the `sort_values()` with `key` and `map`. That is much easier than using Categoricals. And it works with Index too.

Answer (score 19):

## Update

use the [selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13839029/3888719)! it's newer than this post and is not only the official way to maintain ordered data in pandas, it's better in every respect, including features/performance, etc. Don't use my hacky method I describe below.

I'm only writing this update because people keep upvoting my answer, but it's definitely worse than the accepted one :)

## Original post

A bit late to the game, but here's a way to create a function that sorts pandas Series, DataFrame, and multiindex DataFrame objects using arbitrary functions.

I make use of the `df.iloc[index]` method, which references a row in a Series/DataFrame by position (compared to `df.loc`, which references by value). Using this, we just have to have a function that returns a series of positional arguments:

```
def sort_pd(key=None,reverse=False,cmp=None):
    def sorter(series):
        series_list = list(series)
        return [series_list.index(i) 
           for i in sorted(series_list,key=key,reverse=reverse,cmp=cmp)]
    return sorter
```

You can use this to create custom sorting functions. This works on the dataframe used in Andy Hayden's answer:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 2, 'March'],
    [5, 6, 'Dec'],
    [3, 4, 'April']], 
  columns=['a','b','m'])

custom_dict = {'March':0, 'April':1, 'Dec':3}
sort_by_custom_dict = sort_pd(key=custom_dict.get)

In [6]: df.iloc[sort_by_custom_dict(df['m'])]
Out[6]:
   a  b  m
0  1  2  March
2  3  4  April
1  5  6  Dec
```

This also works on multiindex DataFrames and Series objects:

```
months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['New York','Mar',12714],
    ['New York','Apr',89238],
    ['Atlanta','Jan',8161],
    ['Atlanta','Sep',5885],
  ],columns=['location','month','sales']).set_index(['location','month'])

sort_by_month = sort_pd(key=months.index)

In [10]: df.iloc[sort_by_month(df.index.get_level_values('month'))]
Out[10]:
                 sales
location  month  
Atlanta   Jan    8161
New York  Mar    12714
          Apr    89238
Atlanta   Sep    5885

sort_by_last_digit = sort_pd(key=lambda x: x%10)

In [12]: pd.Series(list(df['sales'])).iloc[sort_by_last_digit(df['sales'])]
Out[12]:
2    8161
0   12714
3    5885
1   89238
```

To me this feels clean, but it uses python operations heavily rather than relying on optimized pandas operations. I haven't done any stress testing but I'd imagine this could get slow on very large DataFrames. Not sure how the performance compares to adding, sorting, then deleting a column. Any tips on speeding up the code would be appreciated!

Comment: Would this work for sorting multiple columns/indices?

Comment: yes, but the selected answer is a far better way to do this. If you have multiple indices, just arrange them according to the sort order you prefer, then use `df.sort_index()` to sort all index levels.

Comment: Categorical approach has a lot of limitations.

Answer (score 9):

```
import pandas as pd
custom_dict = {'March':0,'April':1,'Dec':3}

df = pd.DataFrame(...) # with columns April, March, Dec (probably alphabetically)

df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=sorted(custom_dict, key=custom_dict.get))
```

returns a DataFrame with columns March, April, Dec

Comment: This sorts the actual columns, rather than sorting rows based on the custom predicate on the column?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same task but with an addition to sort on multiple columns.

One of the solutions is to make both columns **pd.Categorical** and pass the expected order as an argument "categories".

But I had some requirements where I cannot coerce unknown\unexpected values and unfortunately that is what pd.Categorical is doing. Also None **is not** supported as a category and coerced automatically.

So my solution was to use a key to sort on multiple columns with a custom sorting order:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame([
    [A2, 2],
    [B1, 1],
    [A1, 2],
    [A2, 1],
    [B1, 2],
    [A1, 1]], 
  columns=['one','two'])


def custom_sorting(col: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    """Series is input and ordered series is expected as output"""
    to_ret = col
    # apply custom sorting only to column one:
    if col.name == "one":
        custom_dict = {}
        # for example ensure that A2 is first, pass items in sorted order here:
        def custom_sort(value):
            return (value[0], int(value[1:]))

        ordered_items = list(col.unique())
        ordered_items.sort(key=custom_sort)
        # apply custom order first:
        for index, item in enumerate(ordered_items):
            custom_dict[item] = index
        to_ret = col.map(custom_dict)
    # default text sorting is about to be applied
    return to_ret


# pass two columns to be sorted
df.sort_values(
    by=["two", "one"],
    ascending=True,
    inplace=True,
    key=custom_sorting,
)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
5  A1    1
3  A2    1
1  B1    1
2  A1    2
0  A2    2
4  B1    2
```

Be aware that this solution can be slow.