# ordering dataframe according to a list, matching one of the columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of values. I have a dataframe where one of the columns contains the same values. How do I order dataframe same way list is ordered?

list example:

```
[3,
 4,
...
 21,
 23,
 25,
 26]
```

dataframe example:

```
     0   1    2
0   ND   3  0/1
1   ND   4  0/1
...
11  ND  21  0/1
12  ND  23  0/1
13  ND  25  0/1
14  ND  26  0/1
```

I need to make sure that table is ordered according to the list. Column I need to match is column 1 in the dataframe.

EDIT: replaced sort with order, because sort word is probably misleading

Comment: you need only the *make sure* it's ordered according to the list or do you need to actually order it according to it? (I think it's the latter, but it never hurts to ask)

Comment: make sure that it is sorted according to the list. And if it is not sort it.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23279238/custom-sorting-with-pandas or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838405/custom-sorting-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: not really. I need to check if order in the list matches order in the column. And if it is not matching, order (probably sort is misleading word?) the table according to the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a dataframe based on your list, and merge with your dataframe

```
a = [3,4,1]
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'VAL2' : a})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'VAL1' :[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]})
pd.merge(df_a, df_b,left_on='VAL2',right_on='VAL1',how='outer')
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
df['order'] = df[1].apply(lambda v: l.index(v))
df_you_wanted = df.sort('order')[[0,1,2]]
```

Here l is your list, df is your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple one that worked for me:(you'll first have to make the column you want to order into the index, order, and then reset the index)

```
df.set_index(column)
df = df.reindex(order_list)
df = df.reset_index
```