# How to sort strings with numbers in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sorting

I have a Python Pandas Dataframe, in which a column named `status` contains three kinds of possible values: `ok`, `must read x more books`, `does not read any books yet`, where `x` is an integer higher than `0`.

I want to sort `status` values according to the order above.

Example:

```
  name    status
0 Paul    ok
1 Jean    must read 1 more books
2 Robert  must read 2 more books
3 John    does not read any book yet
```

I've found some interesting hints, using [Pandas Categorical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838405/custom-sorting-in-pandas-dataframe) and [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23279238/custom-sorting-with-pandas) but I don't know how to deal with variable values modifying strings.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: To be clear, do you need integers within your strings to be ordered, e.g. "must read 20 books" comes *after* "must read 3 books" ?

Comment: Yes, but not only that. The order have to be 'ok' first, 'must read 1 more books',...,'must read n more books' and, finally, 'does not read any book yet'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sorted` with a custom function to calculate the indices which would be sort an array (much like `numpy.argsort`). Then feed to `pd.DataFrame.iloc`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Paul', 'Jean', 'Robert', 'John'],
                   'status': ['ok', 'must read 20 more books',
                              'must read 3 more books', 'does not read any book yet']})

def sort_key(x):
    if x[1] == 'ok':
        return -1
    elif x[1] == 'does not read any book yet':
        return np.inf
    else:
        return int(x[1].split()[2])

idx = [idx for idx, _ in sorted(enumerate(df['status']), key=sort_key)]

df = df.iloc[idx, :]

print(df)

     name                      status
0    Paul                          ok
2  Robert      must read 3 more books
1    Jean     must read 20 more books
3    John  does not read any book yet
```

Answer (score 10):

Use:

```
a = df['status'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(float)

d = {'ok': a.max() + 1, 'does not read any book yet':-1}

df1 = df.iloc[(-df['status'].map(d).fillna(a)).argsort()]
print (df1)
     name                      status
0    Paul                          ok
2  Robert      must read 2 more books
1    Jean      must read 1 more books
3    John  does not read any book yet
```

**Explanation**:

1. First [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) integers by `regex` `\d+`
2. Then dynamically create `dictionary` for [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) non numeric values
3. Replace `NaN`s by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for `numeric Series`
4. Get positions by [argsort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16486305/2901002)
5. Select by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for sorted values

Comment: your `'ok'` and `'does not read any book yet'` values should be switched, and the order of the rows reversed.