# Naturally sorting Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, pandas, natsort

I have a pandas DataFrame with indices I want to sort naturally.  Natsort doesn't seem to work.  Sorting the indices prior to building the DataFrame doesn't seem to help because the manipulations I do to the DataFrame seem to mess up the sorting in the process.  Any thoughts on how I can resort the indices naturally?

```
from natsort import natsorted
import pandas as pd

# An unsorted list of strings
a = ['0hr', '128hr', '72hr', '48hr', '96hr']
# Sorted incorrectly
b = sorted(a)
# Naturally Sorted 
c = natsorted(a)

# Use a as the index for a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(index=a)
# Sorted Incorrectly
df2 = df.sort()
# Natsort doesn't seem to work
df3 = natsorted(df)

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(df.index)
print(df2.index)
print(df3.index)
```

Comment: @sethMMorton I supposed I would expect `df3.index` to be the same as `c` while sorting the data to keep it inline with its index values

Comment: It would be nice if `pd.sort` had a `key` option, but it does not. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27009771/1399279) provides a workaround that would let you pass a key generated from `natsort_keygen`.

Comment: I just made an official request to the `pandas` devs to add `key` to the `sort` methods here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9855

Comment: My above issue was a dupe, the active issue is https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3942

Comment: Now that `pandas` has a `key` argument to `sort_values`, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63890954/1399279 should now be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to sort the df, just sort the index or the data and assign directly to the index of the df rather than trying to pass the df as an arg as that yields an empty list:

```
In [7]:

df.index = natsorted(a)
df.index
Out[7]:
Index(['0hr', '48hr', '72hr', '96hr', '128hr'], dtype='object')
```

Note that `df.index = natsorted(df.index)` also works

if you pass the df as an arg it yields an empty list, in this case because the df is empty (has no columns), otherwise it will return the columns sorted which is not what you want:

```
In [10]:

natsorted(df)
Out[10]:
[]
```

**EDIT**

If you want to sort the index so that the data is reordered along with the index then use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas.DataFrame.reindex):

```
In [13]:

df=pd.DataFrame(index=a, data=np.arange(5))
df
Out[13]:
       0
0hr    0
128hr  1
72hr   2
48hr   3
96hr   4
In [14]:

df = df*2
df
Out[14]:
       0
0hr    0
128hr  2
72hr   4
48hr   6
96hr   8
In [15]:

df.reindex(index=natsorted(df.index))
Out[15]:
       0
0hr    0
48hr   6
72hr   4
96hr   8
128hr  2
```

Note that you have to assign the result of `reindex` to either a new df or to itself, it does not accept the `inplace` param.

Comment: Hi, `natsort` developer here.  `natsort` currently does not have any explicit support for handling entire dataframe objects.  What would your expected output be for passing a dataframe object?

Comment: I believe this misses the point.  I realize I can naturally sort the a and used that as the index, but my actual code messes up the sorting of the data frame index because of the manipulations I perform on the dataframe.  I need to resort the index and associated data while it is in the dataframe.

Comment: So what is it you're asking here, you want to natsort the index after data manipulations? You can use `reindex` and call `natsorted` on the index `df.reindex(index=natsorted(df.index))`

Comment: @EdChum Yes, it sounds exactly like that is what they want.  I think ultimately that is the correct answer.

Comment: @EdChum This appears to work but only if I put it in a few dataframe `df2 = df.reindex(index=natsorted(df.index))` performing the operation in place as you show doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @agf1997 Use `inplace=True`

Comment: @EdChum BTW, on my machine `natsorted(df)` returns the columns of the dataframe sorted, which is the same behavior of `sorted(df)`.

Comment: @SethMMorton sorry `reindex` is one of the few functions that does not accept param `inplace`, so yes you have to assign it to itself

Comment: @EdChum That seems like an oversight... sort of like omitting `key` from `sort`!

Comment: @SethMMorton ah that output was based on an empty dataframe, the iterable returned from a df is the columns and yes I get the same result when my df has columns

Comment: @SethMMorton I'm not a pandas dev so I don't know why it's not in there

Comment: @EdChum it's not `sorted(df)` I'm trying to replicate but df.sort().  I believe your reindex trick is a good work around to no key value available for `df.sort()`

Comment: @agf1997 I think Seth was interested as to why I got an empty list, I was just confirming that the behaviour is consistent with `sorted(df)` so unrelated to your question

Answer (score 53):

#### Using `sort_values` for `pandas >= 1.1.0`

With the new `key` argument in `DataFrame.sort_values`, since [`pandas 1.1.0`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.1.0.html#sorting-with-keys), we can directly sort a column without setting it as an index using [`natsort.natsort_keygen`](https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "time": ['0hr', '128hr', '72hr', '48hr', '96hr'],
    "value": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
})

    time  value
0    0hr     10
1  128hr     20
2   72hr     30
3   48hr     40
4   96hr     50
```

```
from natsort import natsort_keygen

df.sort_values(
    by="time",
    key=natsort_keygen()
)

    time  value
0    0hr     10
3   48hr     40
2   72hr     30
4   96hr     50
1  128hr     20
```

Comment: This proposed solution is a bit of a "maximum effort" solution - would not `key=natsort_keygen()` be less effort?

Comment: Agree, updated my answer accordingly. Thanks for the heads up and beautiful package you wrote :) @SethMMorton

Comment: If I try to sort 2 columns of different type, like this `df.sort_values(['Title', 'Copies'], ascending=[False, True], key=natsort_keygen())`, I get this error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`. I got the dataframe from `pd.read_csv`, providing the column names and types. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @Agostino, `natsort_key`  should work, also PyICU is another option for natural sorting.

Comment: @Agostino, a belated response, but with current versions of natsort, it would be `from natsort import natsort_key` and `df.sort_values(['Title', 'Copies'], ascending=[False, True], key=natsort_key())`

Answer (score 35):

### Now that `pandas` has support for `key` in both `sort_values` and `sort_index` you should now refer to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63890954/1399279) and send all upvotes there as it is now the correct answer.

I will leave my answer here for people stuck on old `pandas` versions, or as a historical curiosity.

---

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29581021/1399279) answers the question being asked.  I'd like to also add how to use `natsort` on columns in a `DataFrame`, since that will be the next question asked.

```
In [1]: from pandas import DataFrame

In [2]: from natsort import natsorted, index_natsorted, order_by_index

In [3]: df = DataFrame({'a': ['a5', 'a1', 'a10', 'a2', 'a12'], 'b': ['b1', 'b1', 'b2', 'b2', 'b1']}, index=['0hr', '128hr', '72hr', '48hr', '96hr'])

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
         a   b
0hr     a5  b1
128hr   a1  b1
72hr   a10  b2
48hr    a2  b2
96hr   a12  b1
```

As the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29581021/1399279) shows, sorting by the index is fairly straightforward:

```
In [5]: df.reindex(index=natsorted(df.index))
Out[5]: 
         a   b
0hr     a5  b1
48hr    a2  b2
72hr   a10  b2
96hr   a12  b1
128hr   a1  b1
```

If you want to sort on a column in the same manner, you need to sort the index by the order that the desired column was reordered. `natsort` provides the convenience functions `index_natsorted` and `order_by_index` to do just that.

```
In [6]: df.reindex(index=order_by_index(df.index, index_natsorted(df.a)))
Out[6]: 
         a   b
128hr   a1  b1
48hr    a2  b2
0hr     a5  b1
72hr   a10  b2
96hr   a12  b1

In [7]: df.reindex(index=order_by_index(df.index, index_natsorted(df.b)))
Out[7]: 
         a   b
0hr     a5  b1
128hr   a1  b1
96hr   a12  b1
72hr   a10  b2
48hr    a2  b2
```

If you want to reorder by an arbitrary number of columns (or a column and the index), you can use `zip` (or `itertools.izip` on Python2) to specify sorting on multiple columns. The first column given will be the primary sorting column, then secondary, then tertiary, etc...

```
In [8]: df.reindex(index=order_by_index(df.index, index_natsorted(zip(df.b, df.a))))
Out[8]: 
         a   b
128hr   a1  b1
0hr     a5  b1
96hr   a12  b1
48hr    a2  b2
72hr   a10  b2

In [9]: df.reindex(index=order_by_index(df.index, index_natsorted(zip(df.b, df.index))))
Out[9]: 
         a   b
0hr     a5  b1
96hr   a12  b1
128hr   a1  b1
48hr    a2  b2
72hr   a10  b2
```

---

Here is an alternate method using `Categorical` objects that I have been told by the `pandas` devs is the "proper" way to do this.  This requires (as far as I can see) pandas >= 0.16.0. Currently, it only works on columns, but apparently in pandas >= 0.17.0 they will add `CategoricalIndex` which will allow this method to be used on an index.

```
In [1]: from pandas import DataFrame

In [2]: from natsort import natsorted

In [3]: df = DataFrame({'a': ['a5', 'a1', 'a10', 'a2', 'a12'], 'b': ['b1', 'b1', 'b2', 'b2', 'b1']}, index=['0hr', '128hr', '72hr', '48hr', '96hr'])

In [4]: df.a = df.a.astype('category')

In [5]: df.a.cat.reorder_categories(natsorted(df.a), inplace=True, ordered=True)

In [6]: df.b = df.b.astype('category')

In [8]: df.b.cat.reorder_categories(natsorted(set(df.b)), inplace=True, ordered=True)

In [9]: df.sort('a')
Out[9]: 
         a   b
128hr   a1  b1
48hr    a2  b2
0hr     a5  b1
72hr   a10  b2
96hr   a12  b1

In [10]: df.sort('b')
Out[10]: 
         a   b
0hr     a5  b1
128hr   a1  b1
96hr   a12  b1
72hr   a10  b2
48hr    a2  b2

In [11]: df.sort(['b', 'a'])
Out[11]: 
         a   b
128hr   a1  b1
0hr     a5  b1
96hr   a12  b1
48hr    a2  b2
72hr   a10  b2
```

The `Categorical` object lets you define a sorting order for the `DataFrame` to use. The elements given when calling `reorder_categories` must be unique, hence the call to `set` for column "b".

I leave it to the user to decide if this is better than the `reindex` method or not, since it requires you to sort the column data independently before sorting within the `DataFrame` (although I imagine that second sort is rather efficient).

---

Full disclosure, I am the `natsort` author.