# Numerically sort comma separated strings of numbers

Tags: python, sorting

Looking to sort a set of .csv numeric values column-wise. Optionally, the number of columns varies. For example using Python:

```
        print(sorted(['9,11', '70,10', '10,8,1','10,70']))
```

produces

```
        ['10,70', '10,8,1', '70,10', '9,11']
```

while the desired result is

```
        ['9,11', '10,8,1', '10,70', '70,10']
```

First, sort by the first column, then by the second, etc.

Obviously this can be done, but can this be done elegantly?

Comment: First, iterate once, parse the strings and get the first number as their weights. Create a class with fields like `weight` and `value`. While iterating, create new variables with this class and generate a new list with them. Then sort those objects according to their weights, finally iterate once and collect sorted values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done more elegantly by using the `key` argument of `sorted`:

```
data = [
    '9,11',
    '70,10',
    '10,8,1',
    '10,70'
]

print sorted(data, key=lambda s: map(int, s.split(',')))
```

Result:

```
['9,11', '10,8,1', '10,70', '70,10']
```

With the above code we convert each string of our list to a list of integer values and we use this list of integer values as our sorting key

Comment: yep, and in Python 3 apparently sorted(data, key=lambda s : list(map(int, s.split(',')))) is required. Any way to do this if data is a column in a dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind third-party modules, you can use [natsort](http://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), which is provides the function `natsorted` which is designed to be a drop-in replacement of `sorted`.

```
>>>> import natsort
>>> natsort.natsorted(['9,11', '70,10', '10,8,1','10,70'])
['9,11', '10,8,1', '10,70', '70,10']
```

Full disclosure, I am the package's author.

Comment: useful package, thanks, is there a way to use it with DataFrames?

Comment: @TnatsissaHCraeser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29580978/naturally-sorting-pandas-dataframe