# Natural sort a data frame column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, natural-sort

I would like to apply a natural sort order to a column in a pandas `DataFrame`. The columns that I would like to sort might contain duplicates. I have seen the related [Naturally sorting Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29580978/naturally-sorting-pandas-dataframe)
 question, however it was concerning sorting the index, not any column.

Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a22', 'a20', 'a1', 'a10', 'a3', 'a1', 'a11'], 'b': ['b5', 'b2', 'b11', 'b22', 'b4', 'b1', 'b12']})

     a    b
0  a22   b5
1  a20   b2
2   a1  b11
3  a10  b22
4   a3   b4
5   a1   b1
6  a11  b12
```

Natural sort column `a`:

```
     a    b
0   a1  b11
1   a1   b1
2   a3   b4
3  a10  b22
4  a11  b12
5  a20   b2
6  a22   b5
```

Natural sort column `b`:

```
     a    b
0   a1   b1
1  a20   b2
2   a3   b4 
3  a22   b5
4   a1  b11
5  a11  b12
6  a10  b22
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can convert values to ordered [categorical](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) with sorted catgories by `natsorted` and then use `sort_values`:

```
import natsort as ns

df['a'] = pd.Categorical(df['a'], ordered=True, categories= ns.natsorted(df['a'].unique()))
df = df.sort_values('a')
print (df)
     a    b
5   a1   b1
2   a1  b11
4   a3   b4
3  a10  b22
6  a11  b12
1  a20   b2
0  a22   b5
```

---

```
df['b'] = pd.Categorical(df['b'], ordered=True, categories= ns.natsorted(df['b'].unique()))

df = df.sort_values('b')
print (df)
     a    b
5   a1   b1
1  a20   b2
4   a3   b4
0  a22   b5
2   a1  b11
6  a11  b12
3  a10  b22
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a regex to extract the text and integer parts of your columns, and then sort using them. Wrapping this in a function lets you do it for each column separately with ease:

```
def natural_sort(df, col):
    df[['_str', '_int']] = df[col].str.extract(r'([a-zA-Z]*)(\d*)')
    df['_int'] = df['_int'].astype(int)

    return df.sort_values(by=['_str', '_int']).drop(['_int', '_str'], axis=1)


df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a22', 'a20', 'a1', 'a10', 'a3', 'a1', 'a11'], 'b': ['b5', 'b2', 'b11', 'b22', 'b4', 'b1', 'b12']})

print(natural_sort(df, 'a'))
print(natural_sort(df, 'b'))
```

prints:

```
     a    b
2   a1  b11
5   a1   b1
4   a3   b4
3  a10  b22
6  a11  b12
1  a20   b2
0  a22   b5

     a    b
5   a1   b1
1  a20   b2
4   a3   b4
0  a22   b5
2   a1  b11
6  a11  b12
3  a10  b22
```

Comment: I would prefer a general answer, the format of the data frame values is just for an example.