# Ascending order of Excel rows

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have the following rows in Excel:

[image]

How can I put them in an ascending order in `Python` (i.e. notice how the row starting with 12 comes before that starting with 118).

I think the Pandas library would be a starting point? Any clue is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29582718/2825570)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First read the excel file

```
df = pd.read_excel("your/file/path/file.xls")
df
         data   
0  1212.i.jpg  
1   121.i.jpg  
2   212.i.jpg  
3   512.i.jpg
```

then make a substring of the data 
assuming the column name is "data"

```
df["sub"] = df["data"].str[:-6]
```

Just in case, convert the new column to type int

```
df["sub"] = df["sub"].astype(int)
```

Now sort the values, by that new column

```
df.sort_values("sub", inplace=True)
```

Finaly, if you only want your original data:

```
df = df["data"]


1     121.i.jpg
2     212.i.jpg
3     512.i.jpg
0    1212.i.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `natsorted`

```
from natsort import natsorted
df.data=natsorted(df.data)
df
Out[129]: 
         data
0   121.i.jpg
1   212.i.jpg
2   512.i.jpg
3  1212.i.jpg
```

---

Keep original data index

```
df.loc[natsorted(df.index,key=lambda x : df.data[x] )]
Out[138]: 
         data
1   121.i.jpg
2   212.i.jpg
3   512.i.jpg
0  1212.i.jpg
```

---

Or using `argsort` with `split`

```
df.iloc[np.argsort(df.data.str.split('.').str[0].astype(int))]
Out[141]: 
         data
1   121.i.jpg
2   212.i.jpg
3   512.i.jpg
0  1212.i.jpg
```