# Reordering Pandas Columns based on Column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, columnsorting

I have columns with similar names but numeric suffixes that represent different occurrences of each column. For example, I have columns (company_1, job_title_1, location_1, company_2, job_title_2, location_2). I would like to order these columns grouped together by the prefix (before the underscore) and then sequentially by the suffix (after the underscore).

How I would like the columns to be: company_1, company_2, job_title_1, job_title_2, location_1, location_2.

Here's what I tried from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067027/re-ordering-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-column-name):

```
df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)
```

This resulted in the order: company_1, company_10, company_11 (skipping over 2-9)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of sorting is called natural sorting. (There are more details in [Naturally sorting Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29580978/15497888) which demonstrates how to sort rows using natsort)

Setup with [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/)

```
import pandas as pd
from natsort import natsorted

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[f'company_{i}' for i in [5, 2, 3, 4, 1, 10]])

# Before column sort
print(df)

df = df.reindex(natsorted(df.columns), axis=1)

# After column sort
print(df)
```

Before sort:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [company_5, company_2, company_3, company_4, company_1, company_10]
Index: []
```

After sort:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [company_1, company_2, company_3, company_4, company_5, company_10]
Index: []
```

---

Compared to lexicographic sorting with `sorted`:

```
df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)
```

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [company_1, company_10, company_2, company_3, company_4, company_5]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness, you can also get the desired result by passing a function to `sorted` that splits the strings into `name, index` tuples.

```py
def index_splitter(x):
    """Example input: 'job_title_1'
       Output: ('job_title', 1)
    """
    *name, index = x.split("_")
    return '_'.join(name), int(index)

df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns, key=index_splitter), axis=1)
```