# How to sort a list of lists including numeric strings left to right with an arbitrary number of sorting levels in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, types

I have a list of sublists of arbitrary lengths, populated with strings, both alpha and numeric. I want to sort this list first by the first element of each sub-list, then by the second element, and so on. Numeric strings should be treated as integers or floats, so that for example '100' is placed after '12', not before.

Here’s an example input list:

```
[['10001', '1002', '501'],
 ['10001', '1002', '5001'],
 ['1001', '1002', '5'],
 ['1', '1002', '5'],
 ['1', '102', '6'],
 ['1', '12', '4'],
 ['10', '11', '3'],
 ['mihail', '1', '2'],
 ['1', 'mihail', '1']]
```

The desired output after sorting is:

```
[['1', '12', '4'],
 ['1', '102', '6'],
 ['1', '1002', '5'],
 ['1', 'mihail', '1'],
 ['10', '11', '3'],
 ['1001', '1002', '5'],
 ['10001', '1002', '501'],
 ['10001', '1002', '5001'],
 ['mihail', '1', '2']]
```

That’s the approach I have tried:

```
def true_numeric(string_):
    allowed = '0123456789.'
    for char in string_:
        if char not in allowed:
            return False
    point_count = sum([1 for char in string_ if char=='.'])
    if point_count > 1:
        return False
    return True
```

```
def numeric_strings_sort_key(item):
    result = []
    for element in item:
        if true_numeric(element):
            result.append((0, float(element)))
        else:
            result.append((1, element))
    return tuple(result)
```

```
my_list = [
    ['10001', '1002', '501'],
    ['10001', '1002', '5001'],
    ['1001', '1002', '5'],
    ['1', '1002', '5'],
    ['1', '102', '6'],
    ['1', '12', '4'],
    ['10', '11', '3'],
    ['mihail', '1', '2'],
    ['1', 'mihail', '1']
]

my_list.sort(key=numeric_strings_sort_key)

print(my_list)
```

This code uses a custom true_numeric function to determine whether a string represents a valid floating-point number and treats it as such when sorting. The numeric_strings_sort_key function uses this function to construct a sorting key tuple that correctly handles mixed data types.

However, I’m not sure if this is the best approach or if there’s a simpler or more efficient way to achieve the desired result. Is there a better way to sort a list of lists with mixed data types and an arbitrary number of levels in Python?

Comment: Doesn't `['1', '12', '4']` in your desired output contradict `Numeric strings should be treated as integers or floats` ??? Or do you want to sort only the top_level list? And what about the `arbitrary number of levels` ? Do you mean there can be a list of lists of lists... ?

Comment: if sorted as strings, a hundred '100' goes before twelve '12'

Comment: arbitrary number of levels implies that it could be 2d array of any width. E.g. my_list = [['1', '1002'], ['1', '102'], ['1', '12'], ['10', '11'], ['mihail', '1'], ['1', 'mihail']] should be processed as well. There are two levels of sorting. In the example above there is 3.

Comment: Ok, then depth probably isn't the appropriate word (it suggests embedding depth).

Comment: I especially doubt that my true_numeric() is the way to go. But # print(float('1,234.56'))   # ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,234.56'
# print(float('12a3.45'))    # ValueError: could not convert string to float: '12a3.45'  And also # print(int('123.45'))   # ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '123.45'
# print(int('1,234'))    # ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,234'
# print(int('12a3'))     # ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '12a3'

Comment: Though there are other methods, you could probably get rid of true_numeric and do `try: element = float(element) ; except: pass`

Comment: Thanks! Geat idea, shorter, more adequate

Answer (score 1):

## Writing your own key function

Since all the elements are strings, you need to tell `list.sort` or `sorted` explicitly that strings should be interpreted as integers when possible.

This can be done using the `key` parameter of `list.sort` and `sorted`:

```py
def int_or_not(x):
    try:
        return ('int', int(x))
    except ValueError:
        return (type(x).__name__, x)

def k(l):
    return [int_or_not(x) for x in l]

ll = [['10001', '1002', '501'],
 ['10001', '1002', '5001'],
 ['1001', '1002', '5'],
 ['1', '1002', '5'],
 ['1', '102', '6'],
 ['1', '12', '4'],
 ['10', '11', '3'],
 ['mihail', '1', '2'],
 ['1', 'mihail', '1']]

ll.sort(key=k)

print(*ll, sep='\n')
```

## Using library `natsort`

You're not the first person to want to treat numbers as numbers when they appear mixed with strings. Parsing numbers can quickly become complicated if there is more than one number per string and if you mix integers and decimals and other representations of numbers in strings. Rather than reinventing the wheel, you can use a library that already deals with all the weird edge-cases.

```py
import natsort

ll = [['10001', '1002', '501'],
 ['10001', '1002', '5001'],
 ['1001', '1002', '5'],
 ['1', '1002', '5'],
 ['1', '102', '6'],
 ['1', '12', '4'],
 ['10', '11', '3'],
 ['mihail', '1', '2'],
 ['1', 'mihail', '1']]

ll = natsort.natsorted(ll)

print(*ll, sep='\n')
```

Comment: Oh indeed, I forgot about `natsort`

Comment: @Swifty It's possible that it's overkill in this case, since all strings appear to be either full integer or not a number at all, but when the situation is even just a little more complex, it quickly becomes a great option :) Also, we don't know much about the OP's situation. It's possible that using `key` and `natsorted` are both bad ideas in the OP context, and that instead they should first ***modify*** the list so that numbers are not stored as strings.

Comment: Another question is: is there such a thing in numpy? If there is, it would be superb. Maybe too good to be true :) But any way, the natsort seems to be the wheel, which is invented already. Extremely powerful and concise

Comment: @AntonBibin In numpy no, but in pandas you can use the key functions from natsort: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29580978/naturally-sorting-pandas-dataframe

Comment: @AntonBibin I must admit I've never used an array of strings in numpy, though. Numpy is super-duper-cool for arrays of numbers, but for strings I've never even thought about using it.

Comment: @AntonBibin How did you end up solving your issue? I'm very suspicious about these arrays of strings representing numbers; it's very possible that actually converting all the strings to numbers and dealing directly with arrays of numbers instead of arrays of strings would be a better solution for you than using natsort.

Comment: @Stef At the end of the day I kept the approach of directly defining what the normal case of numeric for humans is
`def is_true_numeric(string_):
    allowed = '0123456789.'
    for char in string_:
        if char not in allowed:
            return False
    point_count = sum([1 for char in string_ if char == '.'])
    if point_count > 1:
        return False
    return True`

Comment: @Stef ...and then made two functions covering the both of my usecases:


`def numeric_strings_1d_sort_key(element):
    if is_true_numeric(element):
        return (0, float(element))
    else:
        return (1, element)`

and


`def numeric_strings_2d_sort_key(item):
    result = []
    for element in item:
        if is_true_numeric(element):
            result.append((0, float(element)))
        else:
            result.append((1, element))
    return tuple(result)`

Comment: @Stef ...which are used like this:

`crop_dict = dict(sorted(crop_dict.items(), key=lambda x: numeric_strings_1d_sort_key(x[0])))`

and like this:

`self.div_fields.sort(key=numeric_strings_2d_sort_key)`

(I am unsure why I chose items() and then [0] in the first case, I just give as is)

Comment: @Stef So the main changes were not due to swaying from the original approach but in considering straight and nested scenarios

Answer (score 0):

Ok I went from your approach, using the shortcut in my comment to make more compact (and hopefully more efficient, though I didn't test that) code:

```
my_list = [
    ['10001', '1002', '501'],
    ['10001', '1002', '5001'],
    ['1001', '1002', '5'],
    ['1', '1002', '5'],
    ['1', '102', '6'],
    ['1', '12', '4'],
    ['10', '11', '3'],
    ['mihail', '1', '2'],
    ['1', 'mihail', '1']
]

def to_numeric(element):
    try:
        return (0 ,float(element))
    except:
        return (1, element)
    
my_list.sort(key = lambda sublist: [to_numeric(element) for element in sublist])
```

The last statement could be rewritten thus (though I'm not sure it improves anything...):

```
my_list.sort(key = lambda sublist: tuple(map(to_numeric, sublist)))
```