# Permute groups in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a `Pandas` `DataFrame` whose data look like

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 30
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.arange(n),
                   'b': np.random.choice([0, 1, 2], n),
                   'c': np.arange(n)})
```

Question: how to permute groups (grouped by `b` column)?

*Not permutation within each group, but permutation in group level?*

---

Example

Before

```
a b c
1 0 1
2 0 2
3 1 3
4 1 4
5 2 5
6 2 6
```

After

```
a b c
3 1 3
4 1 4
1 0 1
2 0 2
5 2 5
6 2 6
```

Basically before permutation, `df['b'].unqiue() == [0, 1, 2]`, after permutation, `df['b'].unique() == [1, 0, 2]`.

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: @jezrael Please see the updated.

Comment: Do you want a random permutation or all possible permutations?

Comment: @ayhan No.  Just one possible permutation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an answer inspired by the accepted answer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838405/custom-sorting-in-pandas-dataframe), which uses a temporary [`Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) column as a sorting key to do custom sort orderings.  In this answer, I produce all permutations, but you can just take the first one if you are looking for only one.

```
import itertools

df_results = list()
orderings = itertools.permutations(df["b"].unique())
for ordering in orderings:
    df_2 = df.copy()
    df_2["b_key"] = pd.Categorical(df_2["b"], [i for i in ordering])
    df_2.sort_values("b_key", inplace=True)
    df_2.drop(["b_key"], axis=1, inplace=True)
    df_results.append(df_2)

for df in df_results:
    print(df)
```

The idea here is that we create a new categorical variable each time, with a slightly different enumerated order, then sort by it. We discard it at the end once we no longer need it.

Comment: Thanks! Nice one.  I'm waiting to see if there are other possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks. I know what you mean, I'm interested to see them too.

Comment: It seems adding a column is necessary, and your method are twice as faster.  Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help!  Good to know re these comparative speeds.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question correctly, you can do it this way:

```
n = 30
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.arange(n),
                   'b': np.random.choice([0, 1, 2], n),
                   'c': np.arange(n)})

order = pd.Series([1,0,2])

cols = df.columns

df['idx'] = df.b.map(order)

index = df.index

df = df.reset_index().sort_values(['idx', 'index'])[cols]
```

Step by step:

```
In [103]: df['idx'] = df.b.map(order)

In [104]: df
Out[104]:
     a  b   c  idx
0    0  2   0    2
1    1  0   1    1
2    2  1   2    0
3    3  0   3    1
4    4  1   4    0
5    5  1   5    0
6    6  1   6    0
7    7  2   7    2
8    8  0   8    1
9    9  1   9    0
10  10  0  10    1
11  11  1  11    0
12  12  0  12    1
13  13  2  13    2
14  14  0  14    1
15  15  2  15    2
16  16  1  16    0
17  17  2  17    2
18  18  1  18    0
19  19  1  19    0
20  20  0  20    1
21  21  0  21    1
22  22  1  22    0
23  23  1  23    0
24  24  2  24    2
25  25  0  25    1
26  26  0  26    1
27  27  0  27    1
28  28  1  28    0
29  29  1  29    0

In [105]: df.reset_index().sort_values(['idx', 'index'])
Out[105]:
    index   a  b   c  idx
2       2   2  1   2    0
4       4   4  1   4    0
5       5   5  1   5    0
6       6   6  1   6    0
9       9   9  1   9    0
11     11  11  1  11    0
16     16  16  1  16    0
18     18  18  1  18    0
19     19  19  1  19    0
22     22  22  1  22    0
23     23  23  1  23    0
28     28  28  1  28    0
29     29  29  1  29    0
1       1   1  0   1    1
3       3   3  0   3    1
8       8   8  0   8    1
10     10  10  0  10    1
12     12  12  0  12    1
14     14  14  0  14    1
20     20  20  0  20    1
21     21  21  0  21    1
25     25  25  0  25    1
26     26  26  0  26    1
27     27  27  0  27    1
0       0   0  2   0    2
7       7   7  2   7    2
13     13  13  2  13    2
15     15  15  2  15    2
17     17  17  2  17    2
24     24  24  2  24    2
```

Comment: Thanks!! Great one.  Just checked with simple profiling @sparc_spread's solution seems faster.  But both works excellent.