# Why doesn't pandas allow a categorical column to be used in groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a custom sorted DataFrame.  To do this I have used `pandas.Categorical()` however if I then use the result of this in a groupby `NAN` values are returned.

```
# import the pandas module
import pandas as pd

# Create an example dataframe
raw_data = {'Date': ['2016-05-13', '2016-05-13', '2016-05-13', '2016-05-13', '2016-05-13','2016-05-13', '2016-05-13', '2016-05-13', '2016-05-13', '2016-05-13', '2016-05-13', '2016-05-13', '2016-05-13', '2016-05-13', '2016-05-13', '2016-05-13', '2016-05-13'],
        'Portfolio': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B','B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
        'Duration': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        'Yield': [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Date', 'Portfolio', 'Duration', 'Yield'])

df['Portfolio'] = pd.Categorical(df['Portfolio'],['C', 'B', 'A'])
df=df.sort_values('Portfolio')

dfs = df.groupby(['Date','Portfolio'], as_index =False).sum()

print(dfs)

                        Date    Portfolio   Duration   Yield
Date        Portfolio               
13/05/2016  C           NaN     NaN         NaN        NaN
            B           NaN     NaN         NaN        NaN
            A           NaN     NaN         NaN        NaN
```

Why is this and how can I overcome this?

Also `SettingWithCopyWarning` is raised is there a better idiom for Categorical?

Comment: This seems a bug related to the combination with the other 'Date' column / using `as_index=False` (both with only grouping by portfolio or with not using as_index=False does work). Would you like to report an issue at https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`as_index=False` is messing something up.  If I run just:

```
dfs = df.groupby(['Date','Portfolio']).sum()
```

I get:

```
                      Duration  Yield
Date       Portfolio                 
2016-05-13 C                18    6.0
           B                10   10.0
           A                 6    1.8
```

I don't know why this is.  It may be a bug.

If you really wanted the result without the index and just have `'Date'` and `'Portfolio'` as columns then use `'reset_index()'`.

```
dfs = df.groupby(['Date','Portfolio']).sum().reset_index()

         Date Portfolio  Duration  Yield
0  2016-05-13         C        18    6.0
1  2016-05-13         B        10   10.0
2  2016-05-13         A         6    1.8
```