# Is there any column match or row match function in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frame lets say:

dataframe A with column 'name'

```
    name
0   4
1   2
2   1
3   3
```

Another dataframe B with two columns i.e. name and value

```
  name  value
0   3     5
1   2     6
2   4     7
3   1     8
```

I want to rearrange the value in dataframe B according to the name column in dataframe A

I am expecting final dataframe similar to this:

```
  name   value
0   4      7
1   2      6
2   1      8
3   3      5
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838405/custom-sorting-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two options:

```
dfB.set_index('name').loc[dfA.name].reset_index()
Out: 
   name  value
0     4      7
1     2      6
2     1      8
3     3      5
```

Or,

```
dfA['value'] = dfA['name'].map(dfB.set_index('name')['value'])

dfA
Out: 
   name  value
0     4      7
1     2      6
2     1      8
3     3      5
```

---

Timings:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
prng = np.random.RandomState(0)
names = np.arange(10**7)
prng.shuffle(names)
dfA = pd.DataFrame({'name': names})
prng.shuffle(names)
dfB = pd.DataFrame({'name': names, 'value': prng.randint(0, 100, 10**7)})

%timeit dfB.set_index('name').loc[dfA.name].reset_index()
1 loop, best of 3: 2.27 s per loop

%timeit dfA['value'] = dfA['name'].map(dfB.set_index('name')['value'])
1 loop, best of 3: 1.65 s per loop

%timeit dfB.set_index('name').ix[dfA.name].reset_index()
1 loop, best of 3: 1.66 s per loop
```

Comment: which is better in terms of time complexity or performance? and how does one find these nuances??

Comment: @HarshavardhanRamanna The main difference between them is `map` would return `NaN` if a value is not found. `loc`, on the other hand, would be missing that row altogether. I've added timings I don't think the performance is very different. The first one is slower but it is mainly because `.loc` is generally slower. When you replace it with `.ix` they are almost the same.