# Grouping and sorting by Month in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with abbreviated month, day_of_month, and some additional data. I am trying group by the month and the sort by the month. But I end up with an alphabetical order in the result. Apr,Aug,Feb... Instead of Jan,Feb,Mar...

Sample code:

```
np.random.seed(1)
n=30
df=pd.DataFrame({'months':np.random.choice(['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'],size=n),
                'data':np.random.randint(1000,size=n),
                 'day_of_month':np.random.randint(1,31,size=n),
                'filename':np.random.choice(['f1','blah','foo','bar','meh'],size=n)})
df.groupby(["months","day_of_month"]).count()
```

Here is the sample output:

```
months day_of_month data filename       
Aug        6         1       1
           24        1       1
           26        1       1
           30        1       1
Dec        10        1       1
           17        1       1
           23        1       1
Feb         5        1       1
           28        1       1
Jan         1        1       1
           16        1       1
           26        1       1
Jul        16        1       1
           20        1       1
Jun        19        1       1
           21        1       1
           27        1       1
```

How do I ensure that the dataframe is grouped by month and day_of_month, and then sorted by the months in proper time order?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838405/custom-sorting-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: @arvi1000 ,Wen, That reference solved my problem. I guess I was too narrow in searching for topic that had 'month'. 
In any case I think I've slightly improved upon the specific case of month, if properly setup, with the following: 
`import calendar
df["months"]=pd.Categorical(df['months'],calendar.month_abbr)`
I seek your advice in whether I should mark this post as duplicate or leave it with the additional info for future; if my contribution with calendar is useful enough.