# Time series data: bin data to each day, then plot by day of week

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a very simple pandas DataFrame with the following format:

```
date        P1      P2      day
2015-01-01  190     1132    Thursday
2015-01-01  225     1765    Thursday
2015-01-01  3427    29421   Thursday
2015-01-01  945     7679    Thursday
2015-01-01  1228    9537    Thursday
2015-01-01  870     6903    Thursday
2015-01-02  785     4768    Friday
2015-01-02  1137    7065    Friday
2015-01-02  175     875     Friday
```

where P1 and P2 are different parameters of interest. I would like to create a bar graph that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8gSo.png) for each P1 and P2. As shown in the data, I have several values for each day. I would like to average the given values for a given day, then plot against day of week (so that the averaged value for Monday week 1 gets added to Monday week 2, etc.).

I'm new to python and my current method is quite nasty, involving several loops. I currently have two dedicated portions of code - one to do the averages and another to go through each day of the week one at a time and tally results for plotting. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for:

```
df[['day', 'P1']].groupby('day').mean().plot(kind='bar', legend=None)
```

and

```
df[['day', 'P2']].groupby('day').mean().plot(kind='bar', legend=None)
```

Full example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
day = np.random.choice(days, size=1000)
p1, p2 = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2500, size=(2, 1000))
df = pd.DataFrame({'P1': p1, 'P2': p2, 'day': day})

# Helps for ordering of day-of-week in plot
df['day'] = pd.Categorical(df.day, categories=days)

# %matplotlib inline

df[['day', 'P1']].groupby('day').mean().plot(kind='bar', legend=None)
df[['day', 'P2']].groupby('day').mean().plot(kind='bar', legend=None)
```

Note that on your existing DataFrame the call to `pd.Categorical` gets you a custom sort key as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838405/custom-sorting-in-pandas-dataframe).

Result (for P1):

[image]

#### Update

In your comment you asked,

> Does groupby find the average of a given parameter (say P1), over all
>   instances of the group? For instance, if I have 8 Mondays, is the
>   resulting value the average of all datapoints that occurred on Monday?
>   An added hurdle here is that I have unreliable sampling for the data.
>   If I had a Monday with 10 samples and a Monday with 1, simply
>   averaging all 11 values would drown out the Monday with a small sample
>   size. Thus, I would like to average all values for a given date before
>   considering the day of week.

Yes, the groupby above would find the average for all instances.  Here's how you could get to that "double" averaging:

```
# for P1; replace P2 with P1 to find P2 avgs.
df.drop('P2', axis=1).groupby(['date', 'day']).mean()\
    .reset_index().groupby('day').mean().plot(kind='bar', legend=None)
```