# Pandas sort_values does not sort numbers correctly

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I have sorted a dataframe by a specific column but the answer that pandas spits out is not exactly correct.

Here is the code I have used:

```py
league_dataframe.sort_values('overall_league_position')
```

The result that the sort method yields values in column 'overall league position' are not sorted in ascending order which is the default for the method.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please paste your code directly into the question, not as images. You can use the {} button to format it correctly. You should do this for the output too.

Comment: It's a column of strings, that's why.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For whatever reason, you seem to be working with a column of strings, and `sort_values` is returning you a lexsorted result.

Here's an example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Col": ['1', '2', '3', '10', '20', '19']})
df

  Col
0   1
1   2
2   3
3  10
4  20
5  19

df.sort_values('Col')

  Col
0   1
3  10
5  19
1   2
4  20
2   3
```

The remedy is to convert it to numeric, either using `.astype` or `pd.to_numeric`.

```
df.Col = df.Col.astype(float)
```

Or,

```
df.Col = pd.to_numeric(df.Col, errors='coerce')
```

```
df.sort_values('Col')

   Col
0    1
1    2
2    3
3   10
5   19
4   20
```

The only difference b/w `astype` and `pd.to_numeric` is that the latter is more robust at handling non-numeric strings (they're coerced to `NaN`), and will attempt to preserve integers if a coercion to float is not necessary (as is seen in this case).

Comment: What if I need to actually handle string values and keep them as such? For example strings "1%", "2%", "10%", "25%", ...? Is there a way of sorting the values by a custom comparator without having to transform the data back and forth?

Comment: @AdamBajger You can lookup "pandas natural sorting column" online.

Comment: @cs95 I just found a comprehensive answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838405/custom-sorting-in-pandas-dataframe/54301218#54301218), thanks for natsorted, though, helped to.

Comment: @AdamBajger oh awesome, I think I know the chap who owns that answer...

Comment: Saved my day, man! The `.astype(float)` worked.

Answer (score 0):

If the dtype of the column should be numeric, then converting to a numeric dtype before sorting is the correct approach. However, if you want to preserve the string/object dtype but sort naturally anyway, you can pass a `pd.to_numeric` as a key to `sort_values()`.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Col": ['1', '2', '3', '10', '20', '19']})
df = df.sort_values('Col', key=pd.to_numeric)
```

This is similar to `sorted(mylist, key=float)` in vanilla Python where the type of the actual data is not modified but that of the keys change. However, unlike `sorted()`, the function to pass as a key to `sort_values()` must be vectorized (as in, it must return the entire column of sorting keys); so `float` cannot work but `pd.to_numeric` can.

A more illustrative example is to sort a column of percentages naturally. In that case, we can pass a lambda function that strips the percentage symbols and converts the column into a numeric one as the sorting key.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Col": ['1%', '10%', '3%', '2%', '20%', '19%']})
df = df.sort_values('Col', key=lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x.str.rstrip('%'), errors='coerce'))
# if the data is clean, can use `astype` as well
df = df.sort_values('Col', key=lambda x: x.str.rstrip('%').astype(float))
```

[image: result]