# Pandas Pivot_Table - Add Grand Total and change Order

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I have the following sample code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
d = {'Fruit': ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Apples', 'Kiwi', 'Kiwi'], 'Amount': 
     [10, 15, 65, 5, 13]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

table = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Fruit', aggfunc= np.sum)
```

The table results appear like this:

```
Fruit   Amount
Apples  75
Kiwi    18
Oranges 15
```

How do you add a grand total to the bottom?  Also, I'd like to choose the order, example:

```
Fruit      Amount
Oranges    15
Apples     75
Kiwi       15
Total      105
```

How do I go about doing this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `margins`

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index='Fruit', aggfunc= np.sum,margins = True,margins_name = 'Total')
Out[141]: 
         Amount
Fruit          
Apples       75
Kiwi         18
Oranges      15
Total       108
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  How about manually choosing the order of the fruit instead of it being alphabetical?

Comment: Check with https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Categorical.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838405/custom-sorting-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: That did the trick!  I used pd.Categorical to manual assign any sorting done to the Fruit series.  Thanks so much!