# How to manually arrange rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a small dataframe produced from value_counts() that I want to plot with a categorical x axis. It s a bit bigger than this but:

```
Age  Income
25-30 10
65-70 5
35-40 2
```

I want to be able to manually reorder the rows. How do I do this?

Comment: Also, you can do `value_counts(sort=False)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can reorder rows with .reindex:

```
>>> df                                                                                                                                                                                             
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

>>> df.reindex([1, 2, 0])                                                                                                                                                                          
   a  b
1  2  5
2  3  6
0  1  4
```

Answer (score 1):

From here [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838405/custom-sorting-in-pandas-dataframe), you can create a sorting criteria and use that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age':['25-30','65-70','35-40'],'Income':[10,5,2]})
sort_criteria = {'25-30': 0, '35-40': 1, '65-70': 2}
df = df.loc[df['Age'].map(sort_criteria).sort_values(ascending = True).index]
```