# How to sort a dataframe based on rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am running multiple dataframes and would like to order them a specific way:
for example:

```
df1

dog
cat
rat
goat
```

```
df2

dog
cat
rat
goat
```

I want to sort rows of a dataframe based on row index labels that i specify. So i want to input(dog,
rat, goat, cat) and receive this result:

```
df1

dog
rat
goat
cat
```

```
df2

dog
rat
goat
cat
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom sorting in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838405/custom-sorting-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort_index`, which also supports doing it in place so you don't have to make a 2nd dataframe.

```
DF1.sort_index(inplace=True, axis=1)
```

The part `axis=1` is telling pandas to sort the columns.

Comment: but how do i tell it i want to order it in a very specific way?

Comment: Oh, so not sorting but specifying the order you want to see it? Just select it that way, like:
DF1 = DF1[['column I want first', 'column I want second'...etc.]]