# How to sort a Pandas DataFrame with multiple columns, some in ascending order and others descending order?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

How can I sort a Pandas DataFrame according to multiple columns, with some of the columns being sorted in **ascending** order while other columns are sorted in **descending** order?

Furthermore, assume that the columns that will be used for sorting have too many unique values to be listed one by one for a sorting key or the `pd.Categorical` function (as suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838405/custom-sorting-in-pandas-dataframe/27009771)).

Here's a small reproducible example:

```py
import pandas as pd

my_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c'],
                      'col2':[1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2],
                      'col3':[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]})
```

Suppose that, in the example above, I wanted to sort `my_df` as follows:

- `col1` in Descending order
- `col2` in Descending order
- `col3` in Ascending order

Comment: Ah, yes it does! I hadn't found that one before. I'll close the question and mark it as solved. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `DataFrame.sort_values` method can handle this very easily. Just use the `ascending` argument and provide a list of boolean values.

```py
import pandas as pd

my_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c'],
                      'col2':[1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2],
                      'col3':[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]})

my_df = my_df.sort_values(by=['col1','col2','col3'], 
                          ascending=[False, False, True])
```

Note that the list provided in the `ascending` argument must have the same length as the one provided in the `by` argument.