# Python pandas: How to sort one of multiple groupby columns to be in a specific/custom order?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to groupby two columns ("Year", and "Size") and then get the count for the number of accidents associated with each size. I was able to do that by this line of code:

```
df.groupby(["Year", "Size"])["Accidents"].count()
```

the output is like:

[image]

**My question is: how to sort one of the groupby columns ("Size") to be in a specific or custom order, such as (V_low, Low, Medium, and High)?** I need also to drop the rows for only the "Size" column if they are nan

The result should be like that:

[image]

thanks for helping

Comment: [Custom sorting in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13838405/15497888) You can make it categorical before grouping. Or `reindex` after. It kinda depends on what you're looking to do.

Comment: `df['Size'] = pd.Categorical(df['Size'], categories=['V_low', 'Low', 'Medium', 'High'], ordered=True)` before `groupby` (this establishes an custom ([Categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html)) ordering which allows all sort operations to order in the column in the specified order) .

Comment: Or [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) after`df.groupby(["Year", "Size"])["Accidents"].count().reindex(index=['V_low', 'Low', 'Medium', 'High'], level=1)` (this will only address ordering once, future sort operations will still be lexicographic.)

Comment: Thanks so much @HenryEcker. I really appreciate it. Your answer works perfect for me.