# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'assign'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, append

I have this dataframe:

```
   SRC  Coup  Vint    Bal   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul BondSec
0  JPM   1.5  2021   43.9   5.6   4.9   4.9   5.2   4.4    FNCL
1  JPM   1.5  2020   41.6   6.2   6.0   5.6   5.8   4.8    FNCL
2  JPM   2.0  2021  503.9   7.1   6.3   5.8   6.0   4.9    FNCL
3  JPM   2.0  2020  308.3   9.3   7.8   7.5   7.9   6.6    FNCL
4  JPM   2.5  2021  345.0   8.6   7.8   6.9   6.8   5.6    FNCL
5  JPM   4.5  2010    5.7  21.3  20.0  18.0  17.7  14.6    G2SF
6  JPM   5.0  2019    2.8  39.1  37.6  34.6  30.8  24.2    G2SF
7  JPM   5.0  2018    7.3  39.8  37.1  33.4  30.1  24.2    G2SF
8  JPM   5.0  2010    3.9  23.3  20.0  18.6  17.9  14.6    G2SF
9  JPM   5.0  2009    4.2  22.8  21.2  19.5  18.6  15.4    G2SF
```

I want to duplicate all the rows that have `FNCL` as the `BondSec`, and rename the value of `BondSec` in those new duplicate rows to `FGLMC`. I'm able to accomplish half of that with the following code:

```
if "FGLMC" not in jpm['BondSec']:
    is_FNCL = jpm['BondSec'] == "FNCL"
    FNCL_try = jpm[is_FNCL]
    jpm.append([FNCL_try]*1,ignore_index=True)
```

But if I instead try to implement the change to the `BondSec` value in the same line as below:

`jpm.append(([FNCL_try]*1).assign(**{'BondSecurity': 'FGLMC'}),ignore_index=True)`

I get the following error:
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'assign'`

Additionally, I would like to insert the duplicated rows based on an index condition, not just at the bottom as additional rows. The condition cannot be simply a row position because this will have to work on future files with different numbers of rows. So I would like to insert the duplicated rows at the position where the `BondSec` column values change from `FNCL` to `FNCI` (`FNCI` is not showing here, but basically it would be right below the last row with `FNCL`). I'm assuming this could be done with an `np.where` function call, but I'm not sure how to implement that.

I'll also eventually want to do this same exact process with rows with `FNCI` as the `BondSec` value (duplicating them and transforming the `BondSec` value to `FGCI`, and inserting at the index position right below the last row with `FNCI` as the value).

Comment: FWIW `pd.DataFrame.append` is really slow and inefficient.

Comment: The issue is your parenthesis are incorrect: `([FNCL_try]*1).assign`. Also, what's with the `*1`?

Comment: If you don't actually care about the order of BondSec groups, I'd recommend using `pd.concat([df, df[df["BondSec"] == "FNCL"].assign(BondSec="FGLMC")])`

Comment: If you *do* care about having your BondSec grouped a certain way, I'd suggest doing all the duplication you need to do first, and then using a [custom ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838405/custom-sorting-in-pandas-dataframe).

Comment: Hi @ddejohn, thank you for your help. I wasn't familiar with `pd.concat` formatting but happy to use it instead. I do care about the ordering, but I can check out the custom ordering link you shared.

Comment: @ddejohn the `pd.concat` you shared did the trick! Now I need to figure out the ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a helper function to handle all your duplications:

```py
def duplicate_and_rename(df, target, value):
    return pd.concat([df, df[df["BondSec"] == target].assign(BondSec=value)])
```

Then

```py
for target, value in (("FNCL", "FGLMC"), ("FNCI", "FGCI")):
    df = duplicate_and_rename(df, target, value)
```

Then after all that, you can categorize the `BondSec` column and use a custom order:

```py
ordering = ["FNCL", "FGLMC", "FNCI", "FGCI", "G2SF"]

df["BondSec"] = pd.Categorical(df["BondSec"], ordering).sort_values()
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Alternatively, you can use a dictionary for your ordering, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54301218/6298712).

Comment: Amazing! Thank you, it worked. I was getting an attribute error when `.reset_index()` was attached to the `pd.Categorical()` call, so I just reset the index of the entire df in a new line.