# Can I manually reorder rows in a column in Python pandas based on a string value?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, data-science

This is my data frame:

```
 "Column 1"         "Column 2"
    XYZ55 Data Tech    128
    XYZ59 Data Tech    117
    XYZ54 Data Tech     53
    XYZ64 Data Tech      7
    XYZ57 Data Tech     12
    XYZ56 Data Tech     10
    XYZ53 Data Tech      9
```

I got this from running the below on my original data frame:

```
counts = df["AssignedGroup"].value_counts(sort=False)
```

My desired data frame:

```
XYZ53 Data Tech    9
XYZ56 Data Tech    10
XYZ57 Data Tech    12
XYZ54 Data Tech    53
XYZ64 Data Tech    7
XYZ55 Data Tech    128
XYZ59 Data Tech    117
```

Am I able to manually pick the order that is outputted as a result of running value_counts(), an order that is not based on an ascending/descending/alphabetic order?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you question, but sort=False orders the data based on the order each value was found first in that column.  What is the logic behind your desired order?

Comment: @ScottBoston there is no specific logic to my order, this is my point. My question was can I reindex/reorder my data frame such that I manually specify the indexes based on a given string. For example index 0 = "XYZ53 Data Tech" or index 1 = "XYZ56 Data Tech"

Comment: Yes, you can.  You can create your order using pd.Categorical and create your own order.  Or set, 'Column 1' as the dataframe index, then use reindex with a list of strings in the order you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom sorting in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838405/custom-sorting-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Inherit and define your custom order.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
class myDataFrame(DataFrame):
    def value_counts(self, custom_order):
        print(f"Hello !! {custom_order}")
m = myDataFrame()
m.value_counts(custom_order="new_order")

>>> Hello !! new_order
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a practical solution…