# Pandas: How to custom-sort on multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with data like:

```
+-----------+-----------------+---------+
| JOB-NAME  |  Status         | SLA     |
+-----------+-----------------+---------+
| job_1     | YET_TO_START    | ---     |
| job_3     | COMPLETED       | MET     |
| job_4     | RUNNING         | MET     |
| job_2     | YET_TO_START    | LATE    |
| job_6     | RUNNING         | LATE    |
| job_5     | FAILED          | LATE    |
| job_7     | YET_TO_START    | ---     |
| job_8     | COMPLETED       | NOT_MET |
+-----------+-----------------+---------+
```

I need to sort this table based on the **Status** and **SLA** states, like for Status: *FAILED* will be top on the table, then *YET_TO_START*, then *RUNNING*, and finally *COMPLETED*. Similarly for **SLA** the order will be *LATE*, *---*, *NOT_MET*, and *MET*.
Like this:

```
+-----------+-----------------+---------+
| JOB-NAME  |  Status         | SLA     |
+-----------+-----------------+---------+
| job_5     | FAILED          | LATE    |
| job_2     | YET_TO_START    | LATE    |
| job_1     | YET_TO_START    | ---     |
| job_7     | YET_TO_START    | ---     |
| job_6     | RUNNING         | LATE    |
| job_4     | RUNNING         | MET     |
| job_8     | COMPLETED       | NOT_MET |
| job_3     | COMPLETED       | MET     |
+-----------+-----------------+---------+
```

I am able to do this custom sorting priority-based only on single column *Status*, but unable to do for multiple columns.

```
sort_order_dict = {"FAILED":0, "YET_TO_START":1, "RUNNING":2, "COMPLETED":3}
joined_df = joined_df.sort_values(by=['status'], key=lambda x: x.map(sort_order_dict))
```

A solution is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838405/custom-sorting-in-pandas-dataframe), but its for single column, not multiple column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend dictionary by values from another columns, only necessary different keys in both columns for correct working like mentioned mozway in comments:

```
sort_order_dict = {"FAILED":0, "YET_TO_START":1, "RUNNING":2, "COMPLETED":3,
                   "LATE":4, "---":5, "NOT_MET":6, "MET":7}
df = df.sort_values(by=['Status','SLA'], key=lambda x: x.map(sort_order_dict))
print (df)
  JOB-NAME        Status      SLA
5    job_5        FAILED     LATE
3    job_2  YET_TO_START     LATE
0    job_1  YET_TO_START      ---
6    job_7  YET_TO_START      ---
4    job_6       RUNNING     LATE
2    job_4       RUNNING      MET
7    job_8     COMPLETED  NOT_MET
1    job_3     COMPLETED      MET
```

Or use ordered [`Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html):

```
df['Status'] = pd.Categorical(df['Status'], ordered=True, 
                              categories=['FAILED', 'YET_TO_START', 'RUNNING', 'COMPLETED'])
                                          
df['SLA'] = pd.Categorical(df['SLA'], ordered=True, 
                              categories= ['LATE', '---', 'NOT_MET', 'MET'])
df = df.sort_values(by=['Status','SLA'])
print (df)
  JOB-NAME        Status      SLA
5    job_5        FAILED     LATE
3    job_2  YET_TO_START     LATE
0    job_1  YET_TO_START      ---
6    job_7  YET_TO_START      ---
4    job_6       RUNNING     LATE
2    job_4       RUNNING      MET
7    job_8     COMPLETED  NOT_MET
1    job_3     COMPLETED      MET
```

Comment: I like the idea of using a single dictionary, but the caveat is that if you have common items in both columns and want a different order, you won't be able to have duplicate keys.

Comment: @mozway - Then is possible use another solution. Also obiously different values.

Comment: as I said, I like it, but the caveat needs to be known IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`numpy.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html), you can use any number of parameters easily:

```
import numpy as np

sort_order_dict = {"FAILED":0, "YET_TO_START":1, "RUNNING":2, "COMPLETED":3}
sort_order_dict2 = {'LATE': 0, '---': 1, 'NOT_MET': 2, 'MET': 3}

order = np.lexsort([df['SLA'].map(sort_order_dict2),
                    df['Status'].map(sort_order_dict),
                    ])

out = df.iloc[order]
```

Output:

```
  JOB-NAME        Status      SLA
5    job_5        FAILED     LATE
3    job_2  YET_TO_START     LATE
0    job_1  YET_TO_START      ---
6    job_7  YET_TO_START      ---
4    job_6       RUNNING     LATE
2    job_4       RUNNING      MET
7    job_8     COMPLETED  NOT_MET
1    job_3     COMPLETED      MET
```

Comment: Great solution!

A small tip is that the primary key that needs to be sorted should be placed at the end.

Comment: @Jeremy yes, `lexsort` reverses the order of the key. In fact it's logical in terms of the sorting steps assuming successive sorts, the last sorting step is the significant one.