# Customizing sort order for Python values count bar plot

Tags: python

I am using this code to create the bar plot pictured below. I need to create a custom order for the bars (not ascending, descending, by values, or using index). It is a mixed set of requests from my client based on each chart in the project. How can I accomplish this?

```py
df['perception_survey'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar',title='I feel happy',ylabel='Number of Respondents')
```

[image: bar plot picture]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom sorting in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838405/custom-sorting-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Can you add a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

See the code below that sorts the x-axis based on a custom order on dummy data similar to yours. Hopefully it helps:

```
import pandas as pd

# init data
df =pd.DataFrame({
    'y': [270, 80, 50,30, 20], 
    'x': ['Always', 'Often', 'Sometimes', 'Never', 'Rarely']
})

# change your order here
order = ['Never', 'Sometimes', 'Rarely', 'Always', 'Often']

df.set_index('x').loc[order].plot(kind='bar')
```

Output:

[image]